# How to create a new List<T> knowing the Type through reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Field f, after I check it and it turns out that it is of type List, I can get its generic type.

But how do I create a new List with this generic type and put new instances inside?

```
if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())) {

    Type genericType = f.getGenericType();
    List<genericType> a = new ArrayList(); // ?????? Error

}
```

---

For example I have a field with type `List<MyObject>`

Is it possible to create an new instance of `ArrayList<MyObject>` through reflections?

Comment: I'm not really sure what are you trying to achieve... could you elaborate?

Comment: Are you trying to create a list with a generic type of the field?

Comment: Generics are a compile time feature.  They doesn't do anything at runtime. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Guys, I'am trying to generate random data for tests. For this purpose I fill all my Entity fields with random values through reflections. But I can not create new List<T> and assign it to the field. But it seems my bad

Comment: If it's just for testing, then you probably should probably just make `List<?>s` and suppress the warnings.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that at runtime.  The best you could do is to create a List<?> and do runtime type checking yourself.

If you're curious why this is, check out "type erasure".  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Alternatively, you could attempt to *clone* the old list, but only the implementations of list have a clone() method, not the List interface, and it will only perform a shallow copy.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

What I normally do is:

```
public void populateListAndSetToField(Field field,Class<?> type, Object instance, Object... params) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<?> list = getGenericList(type, params);
    field.set(instance, list);
}

private <Type> List<Type> getGenericList(Class<Type> type, Object... params) {
    List<Type> l = new ArrayList<Type>();
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        l.add((Type) params[i]);
    }
    return l;
}
```

There are runtime constrains and checks you need to apply but I've used this too many times and it works, thing is when I get to these implementations, the entire surrounding architecture relay on unknown object types, it is tricky.

Comment: I know this seems like an overhead for the question, but I think I understand where you try to go with it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to create a list,

```
// Get the class from the type
Class fieldClass = Class.forName(((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].getTypeName());
// Create a new instance
Object instance = fieldClass.newInstance();
return List.of(instance);
```